# jQuery validation in a while loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, validation

So I am using the jQuery validation plugin to validate textboxes in a php while loop on one of my pages.

The problem that I am having is that the validation only works for the first textbox and not for the rest.

I have tried assigning a unique key rather than validating it with the id of the form, but so far I have not had any luck. It's probably because I am assigning it incorrectly I think.

Here is my script for jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$.validator.addMethod('minNum', function (value, el, param) {
return value > param;
},
"Enter a number greater than 0!");
$("#quantityInputUser").validate({
    rules: {
        quantityInput: {
            required: true,
            minNum: 0,
            number: true,
            maxlength:2
            }
        },
    messages: {
        quantityInput: {
            required: "The quantity is required!",
            minNum: "Enter a number greater than 0!",
            number: "Enter a number!",
            maxlength: "Quantity must be between 1-99!"
        },
    }
});         
});

 </script>
```

And here is the form in the while loop:

```
 while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($itemQuery3)){
                                //some variables are assigned

                                //other stuff happens

        echo "<form action='menu.php' method='post' id='quantityInputUser'>";
                        echo '<div class="row"><h5> Quantity: </h5><input type="number" id="text" maxlength="2" name="quantityInput" value="'.$qty.'"/></div></div>';

         echo "<div class='row'>
         <input class='send' type='submit' name='updateCart' value='Update Cart'/>
         <input name='itemAdjust' type='hidden' value='$itemID'/>
         </form></div>";

}
```

If anybody can point me in the direction of how I would go about assigning a unique key in the form and then referencing it in the script file, it would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Apologies if I didn't make it clear, the forms are created in the while loop, therefore there are multiple forms.

Comment: WHere is the while loop? Are there multiple form?

Comment: If the PHP code you posted is in your `while` loop, then you will be outputting multiple forms, and creating multiple form elements with the same `id` attribute. Please show more of your PHP code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answer is actually pretty close.  You should change it to be a class, like so:

```
echo "<form action='menu.php' method='post' class='quantityInputUser'>";
```

But then your javascript should be more like this:

```
$(".quantityInputUser").each(function(){
    $(this).validate({
    .... rules ....
    });
})
```